# Sort database results starting at specific values first Kohana PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sorting, kohana

I am sorting results from my database, but for one of them i would like to display specific values first, below is the how i am currently sorting them, by `store_type` `DESC`,

```
elseif (Session::Instance()->get('country') == 'it') {
                            $stmt->order_by('`store_type`', 'DESC');
```

this works fine, however i would like to change the order so that values with id 8, 9, 10 are displayed first, then all other results, currently it is starting with id 13 as this is the end of my table and it is sorting `DESC`

Could anybody point me in the right direction on how to achieve this? I am using Kohana framework.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly you have to change DESC with ASC

```
elseif (Session::Instance()->get('country') == 'it') {
                        $stmt->order_by('`store_type`', 'ASC');
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
order by case when store_type in (8,9,10) then 1 else store_type end,store_type DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this ...

```
 order by find_in_set(`store_type`, '10,9,8') desc;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking for the ascending order then just replace your DESC with ASC. if you don't want ans like this then kindly elaborate so that we can help you out.

elseif (Session::Instance()->get('country') == 'it') {
                        $stmt->order_by('`store_type`', 'ASC');

Comment: Not quite, as my results have an id range from 1-13, so if i change to ASC it would start from 1, but i would like it to start at 8,9,10 first then show the rest.